# Creating a back-up list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to create a back-up list of another list in python.  Here is an example of the code.

```
x = [1,2,3]  
y = x  
x.pop(0)  

print y
```

This however yields the result `y = [2,3]` when I want it to yield `[1,2,3]`.  How would I go about making the y list independent of the x list?

Answer (score 17):

A common idiom for this is `y = x[:]`. This makes a shallow copy of `x` and stores it in `y`.

Note that if `x` contains references to objects, `y` will also contain references to the same objects. This may or may not be what you want. If it isn't, take a look at [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Don't forget to mention that `l[:]` is a common idiom.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import copy

x = [1,2,3]
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
x.pop(0)
print x
print y
```

from the [docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

Comment: +1 for copy, because it works with other objects, not just lists. `copy.copy` would do the job in this case, though.

Answer (score 1):

While aix has the most parsimonious answer here, for completeness you can also do this:

```
y = list(x)
```

This will force the creation of a new list, and makes it pretty clear what you're trying to do.  I would probably do it that way myself.  But be aware- it doesn't make a deep copy (so all the elements are the same references).

If you want to make sure NOTHING happens to y, you can make it a tuple- which will prevent deletion and addition of elements.  If you want to do that:

```
y = tuple(x)
```

As a final alternative you can do this:

```
y = [a for a in x]
```

That's the list comprehension approach to copying (and great for doing basic transforms or filtering).  So really, you have a lot of options.